# MongoDB runs FTDC

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I just installed mongoDB and when i activate run it, it runs fine, but it gives me this warning or error:

2017-07-24T12:48:44.119-0700 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK

[mongoDB warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klIOO.png)

Now I have my PATH going to the right place:

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin

I also have my data file in the right place as well: C:\data\db

The folder is full of different files from mongoDB.

I looked into my DBs and everything is still saved and no files have been corrupted or missing.

If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please refrain from posting a screenshot of logs in the future. See [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) for the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that your MongoDB deployment was not shutdown cleanly. This is also shown in the screenshot of the log you posted, where it said `Detected unclean shutdown`. Typically this is the result of using `kill -9` in UNIX environment, force killing the `mongod` process. This could also be the result of a hard crash of the OS.

CTRL-C should result in a clean shutdown, but it may be possible that something interferes with `mongod` during its shutdown process, or there is an OS hard restart during the shutdown process. To shutdown your `mongod` cleanly, it's usually best to send a [`db.shutdownServer()` command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.shutdownServer/) inside the `mongo` shell connected to the server in question.

FTDC is diagnostic data that is recorded by MongoDB for troubleshooting purposes, and can be safely removed to avoid the FTDC startup warning you are seeing. In your deployment, the diagnostics data should be located in `C:\data\db\diagnostics.data` directory.

The WiredTiger storage engine is quite resilient and were designed to cope with hard crashes like this. However, if it's a hardware/OS crash, it's best to check your disk integrity to ensure that there is no hardware-level storage corruption. Please refer to your OS documentation for instructions on how to check for storage integrity, as methods differ from OS to OS on how to perform this.

Comment: I usually close mongod down with control c. is that not the right way to shut down mongod? How would i check my disk integrity to make sure nothing was corrupted?

Comment: @JoeEscobedo edited my answer with more details. Also, checking disk integrity is beyond the scope of the issue, and may be different from OS to OS, even between different versions of the same OS. You may want to check your OS documentation on how to perform this task. There may be some tool that also allow you to check disk integrity, but I'm not an OS expert.